Unable to alter CDC tables
I have an issue with being unable to alter a CDC table that previously caused us no issue.
We run alter statements on our cdc tables to add a column to the tables that we now are starting to face an error regarding.
The query we are trying to run is
ALTER TABLE cdc.dbo_TABLE_NAME_CT 
    ADD processed BIT DEFAULT 0 NULL

Which now returns the following error

Msg 2104, Level 16, State 13, Line 34
Cannot alter the Error: 8277, Severity: -1, State: 0. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
'dbo_TABLE_NAME', because you do not have permission.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.7045.2).
On a 13.0.7029 SQL server we are able to run the alter commands, so it feels like something has changed as part of a patch.
The problem is similar to this issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79075830/error-while-trying-to-alter-cdc-table-on-sql-server
This has happened on multiple environments now out of the blue and previously worked fine, I am unsure if as part of a new patch something has changed causing this.
I know altering cdc tables is not recommended but this didn't cause us any issues previously.
I wondered if anyone had any ideas on this as I'm a bit unsure where to go with this.
I am unsure if this is intended behavior or a bug - there is no mention in the Microsoft service packs that they have done something to disable the ability to add a column to the tables.
More so if this is indeed how things are going to work going forward, we need to adjust accordingly but right now I don't know why this feature has suddenly stopped working.

Cause
This has never been supported.
From the documentation (emphasis added):

For CDC to function properly, you shouldn't manually modify any CDC metadata such as CDC schema, change tables, CDC system stored procedures, default cdc user permissions (sys.database_principals) or rename the cdc user.
Any objects in sys.objects with is_ms_shipped property set to 1 shouldn't be modified.

The change tables are explicitly listed and also have is_ms_shipped set to 1.
These unsupported changes were previously allowed. Since a recent GDR security update, they have caused an error instead.
Consume any pending change data then disable and reenable CDC on the table instead of modifying the system change tables.
Unfortunately, the error message is somewhat mangled. This may be related to error 8277 being missing from sys.messages. Just as likely, there is a different cause. None of that changes the fact that these unsupported changes are now disallowed.
Workaround
If you cannot do this the supported way, enabling global trace flag 150061 will allow your ALTER TABLE statement to succeed.
DBCC TRACEON (15006, -1);

If you want your system to be supported, you should contact Microsoft Support and get them to authorise the use of the trace flag for this purpose.

1 This trace flag is mentioned in KB5042207 - Description of the security update for SQL Server 2016 SP3 GDR: September 10, 2024—but not documented for this purpose.

Thanks this has worked - it will give us some time to adjust the process.
